# How do I add vertical lines between numbers using or without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, debugging

I've created a timer to count down to a specific date, it displays with no problem.  But this time, I'd like to add vertical lines separating them.  I attempted to `borderLeft` and `height` to see a vertical line, but had no luck.  I do see the `1px solid` border, though.  The picture below illustrates what I want to see in the browser.

[image]

I also want the words (days, hours, minutes, seconds) to appear underneath the numbers.  Based on the picture, it appears directly next to them.  I attempted to use `\n` because I thought it would put the word in a new line, but that didn't work.

Do we even need use javascript achieve these things?  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my js:

```
var timerDisplay = document.getElementById("timer");
    timerDisplay.innerHTML = days + "\ndays " + hours + "\nhours " + minutes + "\nminutes " + seconds + "\nseconds ";
    timerDisplay.style.border = "1px solid";
    timerDisplay.style.borderLeft = "6px solid"
    timerDisplay.style.height = "10px";
```

Here's my html:

```
<p id="timer"></p>
```

Comment: make each information inside a span then it's only a CSS matter

Answer (score 0):

You could add inline elements into the p, thus you could apply some styles to achieve your objective.

For example:

```
const timerDisplay = document.querySelector("#timer")
timerDisplay.appendChild(createSpan('126 days'))
timerDisplay.appendChild(createSpan('5 hours'))
timerDisplay.appendChild(createSpan('16 minutes'))
timerDisplay.appendChild(createSpan('33 seconds'))

function createSpan (text) {
  const span = document.createElement('span')
  span.textContent = text
  return span
}
```

And with proper styles:

```
p {
  border: solid 5px black;
  background-color: teal;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: solid 5px black;
}

p span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  width: 150px;
}

span:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you could change your html code:

```
<p id="timer">
  <span class="days">126 days</span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</p>
```

And then, you could change the span elements directly:

```
const timerDisplay = document.querySelector("#timer")
const days = timerDisplay.querySelector('.days')
const hours = timerDisplay.querySelector('.hours')
const minutes = timerDisplay.querySelector('.minutes')
const seconds = timerDisplay.querySelector('.seconds')

days.textContent = '126 days'
hours.textContent = '5 hours'
minutes.textContent = '16 minutes'
seconds.textContent = '33 seconds'
```

And with the same styles:

```
p {
  border: solid 5px black;
  background-color: teal;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: solid 5px black;
}

p span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  width: 150px;
}

span:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

[image]

You can show the example in this jsfiddle: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dkshwofv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As Temani Afif mentioned in comments, you should devide each number to separate span and style them the way you like.

Here is a working example:

```js
function countdown(endDate) {
  let days, hours, minutes, seconds;
  
  endDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();
  
  if (isNaN(endDate)) {
 return;
  }
  
  setInterval(calculate, 1000);
  
  function calculate() {
    let startDate = new Date();
    startDate = startDate.getTime();
    
    let timeRemaining = parseInt((endDate - startDate) / 1000);
    
    if (timeRemaining >= 0) {
      days = parseInt(timeRemaining / 86400);
      timeRemaining = (timeRemaining % 86400);
      
      hours = parseInt(timeRemaining / 3600);
      timeRemaining = (timeRemaining % 3600);
      
      minutes = parseInt(timeRemaining / 60);
      timeRemaining = (timeRemaining % 60);
      
      seconds = parseInt(timeRemaining);
      
      document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = parseInt(days, 10)+' days';
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ("0" + hours).slice(-2)+' hours';
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2)+' minutes';
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2)+' seconds';
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

(function () { 
  countdown('04/01/2025 05:00:00 PM'); 
}());
```

```css
.wrapper {
 background: #0084FF; 
 border: #000 1px solid;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

span:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: #000 1px solid;
}

span {
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="days"></span>
  <span id="hours"></span>
  <span id="minutes"></span>
  <span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
```